# Pytorch: Assign values from one mask to another, masked by itself

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a mask `active` that tracks batches that still have not terminated in a recurrent process. It's dimension is `[batch_full,]`, and it's true entries show which elements need to still be used in current step. The recurrent process generates another mask, `terminated`, which has as many elements as true values in `active` mask. Now, I want to take values from `~terminated` and put them back into `active`, but at the right indices. Basically I want to do:

```py
import torch

active = torch.ones([4,], dtype=torch.bool)
active[:2] = torch.tensor(False)

terminated = torch.tensor([True, False])

active[active] = ~terminated

print(active)  # expected [F, F, F, T]
```

However, I get error:

> RuntimeError: unsupported operation: some elements of the input tensor and the written-to tensor refer to a single memory location. Please clone() the tensor before performing the operation.

How can I do the described above operation in an effective way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few solutions, I will also give their speed as measured by `timeit`, 10k repetitions, on 2021 macbook pro.

The simplest solution, taking 0.260s:

```
active[active.clone()] = ~terminated
```

We can use `masked_scatter_` inplace operation for abt. 2x speedup (0.136s):

```py
active.masked_scatter_(
        active,
        ~terminated,
    )
```

Out of place operation, taking 0.161s, would be:

```py
active = torch.masked_scatter(
        active,
        active,
        ~terminated,
    )
```